# Sharing methods between classes

Tags: python

I have the following convoluted design pattern which I wonder if it is actually a proper (Pythonic) solution.
In the example below I define a `class B` instance that gets initiated with instances of `class A`. It has methods to combine properties and methods of this `class A`, where instances of `class A` in this example have a value AND also refers back to  a `class B` instance so that the instances of `class A` can use the methods in `class B`.
[In the real case `class A` instances are mass objects (earth, moon, sun, etc.) with a method to calculate its own gravity field and `class B` is a calculating class to combine the gravity fields of all the mass objects. When changes are made in a mass object (like its location) the combined gravity field needs to be updated. For some reason I thought it was useful to be able to update the combined gravity field from each mass object].

The principle works however I am not sure a link of the `A class` back to `B class` is actually a good idea as it is a complicated structure and is in the very danger to be too circular [B referring to A and vice versa].
Secondly in the `repr` of class A, I seem to be unable to output the value of the `self._class_b_instance` due to recursion error.
Appreciate your feedback.

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, class_a_objects=None):
        self.class_a_objects = class_a_objects

    def print_doubles(self):
        if self.class_a_objects:
            for i, a_object in enumerate(self.class_a_objects):
                print(
                    f'Instance of class {a_object.__class__.__name__}-{i}, '
                    f'{a_object.double() = }'
                )

        else:
            print('List of objects is empty ...')

    def sum_doubles(self):
        if self.class_a_objects:
            return sum(a_object.double() for a_object in self.class_a_objects)

        else:
            return 0

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.class_a_objects:
            a_objects_repr = [repr(a_object) + '\n' for a_object in self.class_a_objects]
            return (
                f'Instance of class {self.__class__.__name__};\n'
                f'{"".join(a_objects_repr)}'
            )

        else:
            return (
                f'Instance of class {self.__class__.__name__}; '
                f'no class A objects'
            )


class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self._class_b_instance = B()

    def double(self):
        return self.value*2

    @property
    def class_b_instance(self):
        return self._class_b_instance

    @class_b_instance.setter
    def class_b_instance(self, b_instance):
        self._class_b_instance = b_instance

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Instance of class {self.__class__.__name__}, {self.value = }'


def main():
    a1 = A(10)
    a2 = A(20)
    print(f'{a1 = }')
    print(f'{a2 = }')

    print('\nInitiate class class_b_instance')
    class_b_instance = B(class_a_objects=[a1, a2])
    print(f'{class_b_instance = }')
    class_b_instance.print_doubles()
    print(f'sum doubles: {class_b_instance.sum_doubles()}')

    print('\ncalling B methods from A instance a1 (without class_b_instance set)')
    a1.class_b_instance.print_doubles()
    print(f'sum doubles: {a1.class_b_instance.sum_doubles()}')

    print('\ncalling B methods from A instance a1 (with class_b_instance set)')
    a1.class_b_instance = class_b_instance
    a1.class_b_instance.print_doubles()
    print(f'sum doubles: {a1.class_b_instance.sum_doubles()}')

    print('\ncalling B methods from A instance a2 (with class_b_instance set)')
    a2.class_b_instance = class_b_instance
    a2.class_b_instance.print_doubles()
    print(f'sum doubles: {a2.class_b_instance.sum_doubles()}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
a1 = Instance of class A, self.value = 10
a2 = Instance of class A, self.value = 20

Initiate class class_b_instance
class_b_instance = Instance of class B;
Instance of class A, self.value = 10
Instance of class A, self.value = 20

Instance of class A-0, a_object.double() = 20
Instance of class A-1, a_object.double() = 40
sum doubles: 60

calling B methods from A instance a1 (without class_b_instance set)
List of objects is empty ...
sum doubles: 0

calling B methods from A instance a1 (with class_b_instance set)
Instance of class A-0, a_object.double() = 20
Instance of class A-1, a_object.double() = 40
sum doubles: 60

calling B methods from A instance a2 (with class_b_instance set)
Instance of class A-0, a_object.double() = 20
Instance of class A-1, a_object.double() = 40
sum doubles: 60
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are actually asking here. Do you want to know if people agree with you that it's not a good idea?

Comment: @kaya3, indeed. I would like to know to know if passing instances of one class to another class is actually a sound strategy.